# Decorator to cache expensive non-field django model attributes

Tags: django, python-3.x, caching, django-models, decorator

## Edit:

Since my question seems to be too long, I'll add the short version here:

I'm trying to design a `class decorator` that decorates a `class method` and Caches it's return value. But not based on the "self" argument, but "self.id".

### More detailed version:

I have some models, lets say it's something like this:

```
class book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    ...

class vote(models.Model):
    book  = models.ForeignKey( book )
    is_up = models.BooleanField( default = False )
    ...

class comment(models.Model):
    ...
```

And I would like to have a decorator, `ModelCacheAttr` so that I can cache some expensive methods the first time they're used *or calculated elsewhere*.
Like the total number of `upvotes`, `downvotes` and the overall `percentage`.
**Also, It's important to note that models should be cached based on their model_id rather than their python object id.**

And, It should be possible to removed a cache, in-case it has been expired, likely in a related vote's post_save signal.

So lets extend the book class so that it covers all that I said:

```
class book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    ...

    def _update_votes(self):
         U,D = 0,0
         for v in vote.objects.filter( book_id = self.id ):
             if v.is_up:
                 U+=1
             else:
                 V+=1

         self.percentage.set_cache( U / (U + D) if U + D > 0 else 50 )
         self.up_votes.set_cache( U )
         self.down_votes.set_cache( D ) 

    @ModelCacheAttr
    def percentage(self):
        self._update_votes()
        return self.percentage()

    @ModelCacheAttr
    def up_votes(self):
        self._update_votes()
        return self.up_votes()

    @ModelCacheAttr
    def down_votes(self):
        self._update_votes()
        return self.down_votes() 

    @ModelCacheAttr
    def total_comments(self):
        return comments.objects.filter( book_id = self.id ).count()
```

So far, this is what I've written, but i can't access "set_cache" and other methods of the decorator:

```
class ModelCacheAttr( object ):

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f     = f
        self.Cache = {}

    def __call__(self, model, *args, **kwargs):
        print( self, type(self) )
        if model.id in self.Cache:
            return self.Cache[model.id]

        R = self.f(model, *args, **kwargs)

        self.Cache[model.id] = R

        return R


    def __get__(self, model, objtype):
        """Support instance methods."""
        return partial(self.__call__, model)


    def set_cache(self, model, value):  #Doesn't work

        if hasattr(model,'id'):
            model = model.id

        self.Cache[model] = value

    def update_for(self, model):   #Doesn't work

        if hasattr(model,'id'):
            model = model.id

        self.Cache.pop(model, None)
```

Comment: I can't quite tell what your code is doing but it sounds like you should be using the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: I am! look at my current non-working decorator, it has a `__get__` method. The problem kinda *comes* from the descriptor.